# VBA Error "Subscript out of Range" when using Excel Workbooks.Copy

Tags: vba, excel

I have a number of individual Excel workbooks with one worksheet each. I need to copy then into a summary spreadsheet. I tried the following and get Error 9 Subscript out of range.

The error occurs on the workbooks.copy line. If I comment out the "after..." bit, it still falls over with the same error so it must be the workbooks.copy command which causes the error but I can't understand why. Any help much appreciated. Thanks.

```
Sub test()
On Error GoTo testErr
If Len(Dir("z:\September14\Birmingham.xlsx")) <> 0 Then
  If Len(Dir("z:\September14\BirminghamSummary.xlsx")) <> 0 Then
     Workbooks("z:\September14\birmingham.xlsx").Sheets(1).Copy , _
        after:=Workbooks("z:\September14\BirminghamSummary.xlsx").Sheets(1)
  End If
End If
Workbooks.Close
Exit Sub
testErr:
    MsgBox Err.Number & " : " & Err.Description
End Sub
```

Comment: You need to Open both workbooks before you can copy a sheet from one to the other.

Answer (score 0):

As @Ron Rosenfeld suggested, the "Subscript out of range" error is triggered because the workbooks aren't open before you try to copy the sheet. I've defined the workbooks as such to avoid the need to extract the workbook names for use in the `Workbooks.Close` method.

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()
Dim SourceWB As Workbook
Dim DestWB As Workbook

Application.ScreenUpdating - False
On Error GoTo testErr
If Len(Dir("z:\September14\Birmingham.xlsx")) <> 0 Then
Set SourceWB = Workbooks.Open(Filename:="z:\September14\Birmingham.xlsx")
    If Len(Dir("z:\September14\BirminghamSummary.xlsx")) <> 0 Then
        Set DestWB = Workbooks.Open(Filename:="z:\September14\BirminghamSummary.xlsx")
        With SourceWB
            .Sheets(1).Copy , after:=DestWB.Sheets(1)
            .Close (False)
        End With
    End If
    DestWB.Close (True)
End If
Exit Sub
testErr:
    MsgBox Err.Number & " : " & Err.Description
End Sub
```